# Java anonymous iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, anonymous

I have the following Java code:

```
while (pOn[j].iterator().hasNext()) {
  stats.decrement(getNodeCase((int) (pOn[j].iterator().next()), hidden, o));
}
```

Currently, it does not terminate. I suspect this is the case because pOn[j].iterator() returns a new iterator each time. Is there a way to fix this, without assigning the iterator to a temporary variable? Thanks.

Edit: I accidentally included this line which shouldn't be there. 
`pOn[j].iterator().next();`. I have since removed it.

Comment: You are correct as to why that does not terminate. Why don't you want a temporary variable?

Comment: Each time you call `iterator()`, you are creating a *new* iterator, which starts at the first element. Don't do that. Call `iterator()` once and store the iterator in a variable.

Comment: If you don't want to assign the iterator to a temp variable, you can try keeping a count variable and terminate the loop once the count is achieved.

Comment: Why not use the `enhanced for` (commonly named foreach) that addresses your need ?

Comment: Let me introduce you to some magic: `for( Node node : pOn[j] ) { ...do something with node... }`

Comment: Replacing this code with an enhanced for loop isn't the same as assigning the iterator to a temporary variable. The iterator would go two steps per loop iteration, as next is called twice in the loop.

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail about the structure of `pOn`?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The reason why I don't want to use temporary variables is because I have 8 or so of these iterator code blocks, and reassigning the iterator each time would be pretty tedious.

Comment: @john isn't it more tedious for the code not to work? Also, isn't it tedious to write `pOn[j].iterator()` repeatedly?

Comment: @MikeNakis and @ashish I don't think I can do that, since pOn is HashSet[] (an array of hashsets). When I do `for (int x : pOn[j])` I get an incompatible types warning

Comment: Oh @MikeNakis see what you mean, you mean something like:
`for (Object val: pOn[j])
            {
                stats.decrement(getNodeCase((int) val, hidden, o));
            }`

Comment: @AndyTurner Yea it is haha, I suppose it would. I suppose reassigning is only a tiny amount more verbose

Comment: Edit: Thanks mike. This is what I had most closely in mind when I asked this question and probably what I am going to use.

Answer (score 0):

`.iterator()` is returning new iterator from first element. Put the iterator in a variable.

```
Iterator itr = pOn[j].iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  stats.decrement(getNodeCase((int) (pOn[j].iterator().next()), hidden, o));
  itr.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing the wrong conclusion from your problem. You say you have 8 similar blocks, and that you therefore do not want to use a local variable.

Although that already led you to writing incorrect, buggy code.

You see - the problem is not an additional variable for that iterator. It is the fact that you have those 8 blocks already.

So the answer here: step back, identify the common parts in your code and create helpful abstractions (probably a number of small helper methods) to eliminate the code duplication coming from those 8 blocks. You see, when you find a way to hide that loop in a helper method - would you really care any more about the variable used for that iterator?